# Map fragment in coordinator layout overlapping bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to display a bottom sheet on top of my Map using Coordinator layout. The sheet appears for a moment, and then disappears when the Map is created. The sheet then disappears. 
The sheet is supposed to expand on marker click. The logcat shows that the sheet is expanded when the marker is clicked.

Below is my function in MapActivity

```
 void setupMap() {

    View fml= findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);

        final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(fml);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN");
                        break;



            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "slideOffset: " + slideOffset);
            }
        });




        mMap.setPadding(2, 250, 2, 2);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Log.d("markerclick", "onMarkerClick: ");

                _marker = marker;



                if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }else {
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                }
                fml.bringToFront();


                return true;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);




    }
}
```

This is the xml file for Map Activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

>
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gps"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/autotxt_serchMap"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_serchMap"
            android:src="@drawable/search2"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:translationY="@dimen/docorPopupFragmentHeight"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:id="@+id/doctorDetailFrame">
          android:translationY="@dimen/docorPopupFragmentHeight"
     </FrameLayout>!-->


</RelativeLayout>
<include
    layout="@layout/docdetail"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

Bottom Sheet layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:uber="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RelativeLayout>
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scheduleLayout"

        android:gravity="center">


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/DocDet_MondayChkBx"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/DocDet_MondayTo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:enabled="false" />


        </RelativeLayout>

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:textSize="18dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your guidance will be appreciated